# Add rules using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, range, rules

I have one dropdown menu named as `dlUserRole`. Inside of it, there are 2 values with index `0` and `1`.

I am trying to apply rules for the field `ddlSupervisor`, like a validation such that if selected index of `ddlUserRole` is 0 there should be no selection or rule in `ddlSupervisor`, otherwise there should be at-least 1 selection in `ddlSupervisor`.

I have a working code for 2 values in `ddluserRole` dropdown. Now, I added 3rd filed there and I want to apply the same rule, but on selection of 3rd field from `ddluserRole` (and though I made a choice in `ddlSupervisor`), I am getting error as

```
"Please select value between 0 and 1 "
```

... My half working jQuery code as follows:

```
$('#ddlUserRole').change(function () {
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById('ddlUserRole');
    if (selectedValue.selectedIndex == '1') {
        $("#ddlSupervisor").rules('add', {
            range: [1, @double.MaxValue],
            messages: {
                range: "Please Enter Supervisor"
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#ddlSupervisor").rules('add', {
            range: [0, @double.MaxValue],
        });
    }
});
```

I changed the condition to

```
if (selectedValue.selectedIndex == '1' || selectedValue.selectedIndex == '2')
```

... but not worked yet. How should I make the above validation?

Comment: You mentioned 2 ids in description, I see the same in code, they are 2 separate selects/options groups correct?

Comment: @zer00ne - yes correct

Comment: You're using Validate jQuery plugin, correct? Did you initialize the plugin on a `<form>` tag first ? Perhaps you should post the HTML as well. When you use `.rules()`, I think you need to meet those 2 requirements first: 1. a `<form>` tag and 2. Validate plugin needs to be initialized on said `<form>` tag like so: `$('form').validate({option});`. That is if you are using Validate plugin...Btw I don't recognize that value `@double.MaxValue` where did it come from?